# PHP variable not echoing if wrapped in < >

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo an email list for all the students in my database, but the `$email` variable is not echoing unless I remove the < > from the below code. Is it trying to read `$email` as HTML or something? How would I do this correctly?

```
$students = $users->student_list($item);

foreach ($students as $student) {
     $email     = $student['payer_email'];
     $first     = $student['first_name'];
     $last  = $student['last_name'];
     echo "$first $last  <$email>, ";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo "$first $last  <$email>, ";` probably echos `<mike@site.com>` which browser thinks as a tag and tries to parse it (you can view the page source to verify). you should use following avoid this issue

```
echo "$first $last  &lt;$email&gt;, ";
```

or use following

```
echo htmlentities("$first $last  <$email>, ");
```

PHP will automatically convert `< >`

Answer (score 2):

The web browsers consider `<` & `>` as start and end for defining a tag. Your code generates `<john@example.com>` and the browser thinks this is a tag. You have to use HTML Entities :

```
echo "$first $last  &lt;$email&gt;, ";
```

Answer (score 2):

It's being interpreted as an HTML tag, yes. Your safest bet (for both the email and name) is to encode the strings with [htmlspecialchars()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before displaying them:

```
$email     = htmlspecialchars("<" . $student['payer_email'] . ">");
$first     = htmlspecialchars($student['first_name']);
$last      = htmlspecialchars($student['last_name']);
echo "$first $last  $email, ";
```